# What is the command to 'graphically' display a menu structure in *nix?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I am currently learning the Zend framework and in the documentation it displays the directory structure graphically - using ascii.

I am sure there must be a *nix command to create this display - is there? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)